# Solve ODE with time dependent value

Tags: matlab, ode

I need help solving the following differential equation using the function ode45 from matlab.
The issue I have is a time dependent function on the equation.
Equation:
d(C(t)*W(t))/dt = F1-F2
F1 and F2 are constants that I would like to pass on to the function. 
Here is an example of the code I'm using right now. In order to solve the ODE I'm using Euler's Method but I would like to use ODE45 or the appropiate ODE solver in order to compare results. Error values in Euler's Method could lead to false information.

```
T  = 0.0125;        %Duration (minutes)
dt = 0.01*T;       %Time step duration (minutes)
nsteps = 15*T/dt;   %Total number of timesteps
R = 0.01;           %Resistance
P1 = 2;             %Pressure 1
P2 = 5;             %Pressure 2
P3 = 80;            %Pressure 3
F1 = (P1-P2)/R;     %Flow 1
F2 = (P2-P3)/R;     %Flow 2
Cmin = 0.00003;     %Min value of Cfunction
Cmax = 0.0146;      %Max value of Cfunction
tplot = zeros(1,nsteps); %Allocate memory to save values.
P3plot = zeros(1,nsteps); %Allocate memory to save values.
%EULER'S Method.
for i=1:nsteps
    t = i*dt;
    Cnew = Cfunction(t+dt,Cmin,Cmax);
    Cold = Cfunction(t,Cmin,Cmax);
    P3 = ((F1-F2)*dt/Cnew)+((Cold*P3)/Cnew);
    P3plot(i) = P3;    %Save pressure values.
    tplot(i) = t;         %Save time values
end
plot(tplot,P3plot)
```

And this is the function for C:

```
function CV=Cfunction(t,CVS,CVD)
T =0.0125;          %Duration 
TS=0.0050;          %Duration 
tcS=0.0025;         %time constant
tcD=0.0075;         %time constant
tc=rem(t,T);        % tc=time in the current cycle, 
if(tc<TS)
  e=(1-exp(-tc/tcS))/(1-exp(-TS/tcS));
  CV=CVD*(CVS/CVD)^e;
else
  e=(1-exp(-(tc-TS)/tcD))/(1-exp(-(T-TS)/tcD));
  CV=CVS*(CVD/CVS)^e;
end
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you looked through the documentation, e.g., [this page on numerically solving ODEs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/ordinary-differential-equations.html), and tried any examples? This is a programming site so you should edit your question to turn the equation into code.

Comment: I went ahead and edited the post to include the current code I have. However, I'm not using any of the ODE solvers. To solve the ODE I'm implementing Euler's Method. I would like to find out how to solve the ODE using any of the solvers in order to compare results and determine the error values of using Euler's Method.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your equation has a simple analytic solution. Assuming all arguments are double, Whandle is a function handle and Whandle(t) is nonzero, integration over [0,t] etc.

```
function y = C(t, Whandle, F1, F2)
   y = 1/Whandle(t) * (F1 - F2) * t
end
```

Comment: I looked back at the equation I originally put in the question and realized I've made a mistake, which I corrected. Both C and W are functions dependent on time.

Comment: It doesn't matter, equation still integrable, just edited my answer